# Studying diophantine magic squares

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, puzzle, cryptarithm

### A bit of context

I'm analyzing a type of cryptarithmetic puzzle that consist in the simultaneous resolution of 6 cryptarithms arranged in a magic square fashion.
Here's an example:

[image: https://www.iread.it/arithmogriphs.php]

Solution:

> `7008, 612, 6396 // 584, 571, 13 // 12, 41, 492`

My goal is possibly finding how many puzzles are there (with numbers up to $k$ digits) net of symmetries.
I've started calculating how many unique structures of operations are there up to symmetries.

Since *(assuming the number $0$ is never used otherwise the puzzle would be trivialized)* the result of each of the four operations can always be swapped with the first operand and the operation inverted

- you can always swap the first column(row) with the last one and invert all the row(column) operations.

  ```
  These four puzzles are equivalent

    +   =       -   =       *   =       /   =  
  /   -   +   +   -   /   *   +   -   -   +   *
    -   =       +   =       -   =       +   =  
  =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =
    *   =       /   =       +   =       -   =
  ```

In addition

- if a column(row) consist of only $+$ and $\times$ you can swap the first column(row) with the second
- if a column(row) consist of only $-$ and $\div$ you can swap the second column(row) with the third

And of course

- you can always transpose the entire matrix

[I've written a code](https://tio.run/##pZLBitswEIbP8VNsMeQ0rmMn7KHBi5YNgYUthCRLD0ItajJxBLbsSvL2IPzs6dibuNu0h9IeDL9GM59nRn8p3RFL6dROnlDvbrKbpanKhcqVs/xBOtT0sTB@7/0Ekja6mwCJqFMJ@AQmJFLw0auatjAT43mwx460ksYppyrNH7XDHM0ZG8IMbgUhJ9FdT4WkF0SFlFTHgimJnkqyQwa5QWrFbL7Lmtjbo6ma/Mi9D8N2DH6NL2gsdZpAFKZdJCI5RLtIdD7FrK9peRiKjlygtQP3Y7VvCuT@kG0rJ4s4ZuH4taCFYPSsu2mC0ejxwO@/Wn7gPBFCZNkU3rTHKD@BFZqyccjDFNaEcviEB8cvHdGQKdC6NirX7IwRLfhWwC/49I/4gZ38DbtjCKAdXOOJ7Kdd5v/T/3XaYCSC/nnxW6NeZEEexF0hreX6i/iQ0TFmCyzQ4aKpC3KpQ8uWhXTkTD6Y4E3/8PM5zy/MaCQyJNODHfoTeU3E8aYybn5qtOpvyABrqXPkE5h9vo0SMQ8M1gYtapqJcixl@HYefDoqcsml7F3mW7iva9T7bcWvKmCpjHXskivmF5U9VGVdYEmZAwl@W8NVtRBBsDJKO3b1m3P0CXXujteXp9MP) that given a structure finds all the members of its equivalence class.
*If my analysis and my code are correct,* **there are $433$ unique structures of operations.**

Hence $433$ different systems of diophantine equations. ($9$ of them consist of only $+$ and $-$ and $9$ of them consist of only $\times$ and $\div$, those are trivial)

### The question

A general form of this class of diophantine equations is:

$$ (a \star_1 b) \star_2 (c \star_3 d) = (a \star_4 c) \star_5 (b \star_6 d) $$

$a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ (a \star_1 b),\ (c \star_3 d),\ (a \star_4 c),\ (b \star_6 d),\ (a \star_1 b) \star_2 (c \star_3 d) \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

How can I find the solutions or determine there are none? Is there a simple algorithm?